# XSLT escape all entities except <p> <br> <b> <a>

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a small problem with xslt

i have this text

```
newline<br /> <br /> newline<br /> <br /> <br /> newline<br /> <br /> <br /> newline<br /> <br /> <b>asdasdasd</b><br /> <br /> <script>alert(0)</script>
```

I want to escape all entities except `<p> <br> <b> <a>`, therefore when i use

```
<xsl:value-of select="page/@post_content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

to be able to bold text, insert an link ... etc, but `<script>` tag to be escaped but not stripped with strip_tags ... but when i let `disable-output-escaping="yes"` i get a message, so there is XSS vulnerability here ...

my php code is

```
$hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("post_content",nl2br($PostContent));
```

So how can i do this?

PS : I'm very concerned about security! Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just put the elements with no output escaping you want to have? If you are concerned about security you could do a white-list approach. And you should not just disable output escaping for all child elements, that's obviously wrong.

Comment: i don't really know what to do, i believe this is a simple problem, yet i didn't founded the answer, what is your idea, to having PHP to do this or XSLT?

Comment: so are you applying that disable-output-escaping should be no all the time?

Comment: IIRC it should be possible that you tell in the select attribute which tags should not be escaped, probably with a xpath union (`|` operator). Okay, I see this is an attribute. You would need to treat the attribute value as XML as well. You should probably add the XML as well to your question and some code so it's more clear what you're doing.

Comment: isn't there a simple solution? because it's a simple problem, just outputting something ..

Comment: Well, you have a kind of serialized value here that needs understanding about what a tag is and then the names of the tags you want to preserve. The problem might look simple for you, but it's not a straight forward "one thing to do" operation. If you share more, we might come to a simple solution, however, the way until is a bit rough.

Comment: it is strange, how about transforming all <br /> into /n and then htmlentities() all, then transform /n back in <br /> then having disable-output-escaping="yes", what do you think?

Comment: I wonder how you can have that inside an attribute at all, you should really add your XML as I've already written. Add some facts,  assumptions and talks about "strange", "esoteric", "Must be simple/easy/sweet" are not really helpful.

Comment: i understand you, and i see that you are good in programming, so can you have a look over my code to see if i have the right aproach? and try to not be harsh with me, i'm trying to learn ... http://codepad.org/kvxSi1qB and http://codepad.org/iNm5acN8 => i solved this with that 2 lines at PHP 101 102 ....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12940/discussion-between-hakre-and-row-minds)

Comment: You forgot to provide the wanted result. In its current form you haven't a real, meaningful question. Please, edit the question and provide the missing information.

Comment: Did you actually read the question? It's quite clearly described.

Comment: Flynn1179: Yes I have re-read the question many times and I still don't see what is the source XML document and what is the required result -- none is provided. Also, there are no entities in the provided fragment, so it is very confusing what "entities" the OP has in mind.

Comment: Are you being deliberately pedantic, or are you really that incapable of understanding a question that isn't perfectly laid out using precisely the correct terms? It's extremely obvious that by 'entities', he means 'elements', from the examples given. I really don't understand how that can't be obvious to anybody but the most novice XML user.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I am not a clairvoyant or a psychiatrist and none of us need be such. If someone has problems with their terminology for this particular subject-matter, they have biger problems than what is in their posts. In particular, someone that doesn't know what elements are for XML -- obviously needs to read an introductory source on this matter, before posting a question at SO -- in other words, they need to learn the alphabet before they start writing.

Comment: Row Minds: Do have a look at how the XPath Visualizer (http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) does this.

Comment: $PostContent = htmlentities($PostContent);
   $PostContent = nl2br($PostContent);
   $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("post_content",$PostContent);

Comment: this is how i solve in php my newline problem ...

Answer (score 0):

XSLT isn't really designed for this, whilst you could do it using XSLT 2.0 using a [Regular Expression](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html), this is not the version of XSLT you are using and PHP currently doesn't use XSLT 2 by default. You better doing it in your back-end programming language (such as PHP).

I realise you say you don't want to use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is there any reason for it? It does allow you to specify what tags you are able to keep.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 =/= XSLT 1.0 (and per default in PHP only XSLT 1.0).

Comment: i know, but what strip_tags does, it actually make <script>alert(0)</script> to be alert(0)

Comment: Ahh so you want to have the html tags just escaped rather than stripped. Gimme a few mins

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time doing this with XSLT if you put the post_content into an attribute value, as the attribute's just going to contain one big long string. What happens if the user enters invalid HTML?

If you put the xml directly into an element called 'post_content' instead, you can use these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="post_content">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="post" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="post">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="post"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p | br | b | a" mode="post">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="post"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It's a little crude, but basically, the idea is that any `p`, `br`, `b` or `a` elements are picked up by the last template and copied 'as-is', and anything else is picked up by the `*` template, and rather than using an actual element, it outputs escaped text instead. The first template is just there to make sure any elements within it are processed using the 'post' mode, so these templates won't accidentally process anything else they shouldn't.

Comment: i have done this with PHP like    $PostContent = htmlentities($PostContent);
   $PostContent = nl2br($PostContent);
   $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("post_content",$PostContent);